# How to make cross component calls?

Tags: reactjs

i have the following two components on two separate jsx files

**1. on `Component1.jsx` :**

```
    var Comp1 = React.createClass({
          componentDidMount: function() {
            this.comp1Fn();
          },
          comp1Fn: function() {
            console.log('Component 1 created');
            test1();
          },
          render: function() {
              return ( < div > < input type = "button"
                value = "Componenet 1" / > < /div>)
        }
    })

    function test1(){
        console.log('called test1');
    }


    var c1= ReactDOM.render(<Comp1 / > ,
                document.getElementById('div1'));
```

**2. on `Component2.jsx` :**

```
var Comp2 = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount:function(){
        this.comp2Fn();
    },
    comp2Fn:function(){
        console.log('trying to call comp1fn function of Component 1');
        c1.comp1Fn(); //****calling the function comp1Fn of the Comp1*****
    },
    render:function(){
        return(<div><input type="button" value="Component 2"  /></div>)
    }
})


var c2= ReactDOM.render(<Comp2 />,
    document.getElementById('div2'))
```

**Here is the HTML for it:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head lang="en">
</head>
<body>   
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="Component1.jsx"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="Component2.jsx"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

in the Comp2's `comp2Fn()`, it calls `c1.comp1Fn()`. But it gives the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: c1 is not defined
>       at Constructor.comp2Fn (eval at n.run (browser.min.js:3), :12:9)
>       at Constructor.componentDidMount (eval at n.run (browser.min.js:3), :8:14)
>       at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (react.js:839)
>       at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (react.js:12909)
>       at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (react.js:16039)
>       at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (react.js:15986)
>       at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (react.js:11190)
>       at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (react.js:15973)
>       at Object.batchedUpdates (react.js:9229)
>       at Object.batchedUpdates (react.js:13702)

[image]

1. why i cannot access the function `comp1Fn()` of `Comp1`?
2. How do i call `comp1Fn()` from Comp2 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access Comp1 in Comp2, just export Comp1 and import to Comp2.

For example

```
export default Comp1
// Then import to Comp2
import Comp1 from 'your/path/to/Comp1
```

Then you can access Comp1 in Comp2

Comment: when i put those lines i get the following error:Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at eval (eval at n.run (browser.min.js:3), <anonymous>:4:23)
    at Function.n.run (browser.min.js:3)
    at l (browser.min.js:3)
    at browser.min.js:3
    at XMLHttpRequest.s.onreadystatechange (browser.min.js:3)